# DataTables sorting by time rather than date order

Tags: datatables

I have a datetime field which is displaying fine in dataTables. However, it seems to be sorting in time order rather than date order. The latest entry should be first in the list but it isn't. I have done a grab which shows the problem and would be grateful if someone could point out my error.

Thanks

DataTables v1.10

```
{
  mData: 'ddate',
  render: function(mData) {
    return moment(mData).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
}, {
  mData: 'date',
  render: function(mData) {
    return moment(mData).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  }
},
    "order": [[ 
       9, "asc" 
    ]]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks as though you'll need to have a custom sort on that column. This might help: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment

Comment: @annoyingmouse sorry should have said that I am using moment already. I shall update my quesion code. Thanks

Comment: I'm at a loss @user1532468 I've tried replicating your issue here and can't duplicate it: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/xpvt214o/61630/

Answer (score 0):

As annoyingmouse said, you can use DataTables plugins - this page [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) has several date/time format sorts, so you could use as-is or tweak to suit your needs.